# AngularJS call function from click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't call this function in my controller.

On clicking an `accordion-group` attribute I get this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: getConversationsForUser is not defined`

Here is the html:

```
<ui-view id="smtConvoCard" layout="column" layout-fill layout-padding>
    <div layout="row" flex layout-align="center center">
        <md-card flex-gt-sm="90" onresize="resize()" flex-gt-md="80">
            <md-card-content>
                <md-list>
                    <h2>Conversations</h2>
                    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                        <accordion-group heading="{{contact.FirstName}} {{contact.LastName}}" ng-repeat="contact in contacts" onclick="getConversationsForUser(contact.UserUID)">
                            <div>Test</div>
                        </accordion-group>
                    </accordion>
                </md-list>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</ui-view>
```

Here is the controller being used (partial code):

```
controller('convCtrl', ['$scope', 'messageFactory', function ($scope, messageFactory) {
        var currentUser = helpers.storage.get('UID');
        $scope.contacts = [];

        $scope.getContacts = function () {
            /*Does stuff*/
        };

        //This is the function it is trying to call
        $scope.getConversationsForUser = function (userUID) {
            /*Does stuff*/
        };

        //Setup
        $scope.getContacts();
    }]);
```

I've tried changing the `onclick` even to a different element, calling the `getContacts` function instead and I always get `Uncaught ReferenceError`

I know that function is within my scope because I'm data binding the `contacts` variable to the page.

Comment: because its defined on your $scope, not in global space which onclick requires, you are wanting `ng-click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<accordion-group heading="{{contact.FirstName}} {{contact.LastName}}" ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-click="getConversationsForUser(contact.UserUID)">
    <div>Test</div>
</accordion-group>
```

And don't forget to insert a `ng-controller="convCtrl"` in an element wrapping your `accordion`.

**UPDATE**

I add a little explanation : the $scope in a controller `MySuperController` have to be linked in the DOM via a `ng-controller="MySuperController"` attribute added to a tag (= a DOM element), so that your $scope variable will represent any variable within this controller.

As soon as you create a function attached to this scope (`$scope.myFunction = function () { /* ... */ }`), you can then call it, i.e., when an event is fired. This is the case via the `ng-click` directive that attaches an event handler to the element on which it's set as an attribute.

Comment: Please do not just put `Try ...code block here...` explain what you changed and why they should use it.